# New badge for reputation-saving edits

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

In honor of my heroic edit of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10589583/256138), I propose a new badge, named `Grandmaster of Altruism` to award those who selflessly give up their shot at momentary fame and quite a lot of reputation to help a misguided user that has posted an admirable, but in the end, wrong, answer to a question.

The result is a friendlier site experience for all, as expressed by these two members in the comments relating to the affair:

> [What was going on here is that users were jealous of H2CO3 getting rep for an answer essentially given by rubenvb, even though all that should matter is that another correct answer is now close to the top. (Upvotes should be given according to the correctness of the answer, not according to whether the user getting them would "deserve" them.) - sbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589559/shortest-way-to-calculate-difference-between-two-numbers/10589583?noredirect=1#comment13732337_10589583)

and

> [Then we should be applauding rubenvb for his altruism and demonstrating the unique nature of our site and demonstrating how answers can be improved for the good of everyone. Sorry for the two rollbacks everyone, I automatically assumed something bad was going on here :) - Kev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589559/shortest-way-to-calculate-difference-between-two-numbers/10589583?noredirect=1#comment13732683_10589583)

The badge should obviously be golden, if not platinum, to express how deeply appreciated and cherished these random acts of kindness must be on the Stackexchange network.

Comment: You could also just post the correct answer :) Yum the upvotes !

Comment: How would this be detected? As opposed to a more trivial edit. Also; are you supposed to be making wholesale changed to large parts of answers?

Comment: You can always start a bounty and award it to the answer.

Comment: @JBL that would defeat the altruistic nature of the act of kindness, now wouldn't it. Also note I actually helped the OP understand where he went wrong by way of a nice comment. Unfortunately, part of the conversation has been lost.

Comment: I'm still kind of dubious about this, now you ended up being correct but wouldn't the right thing to do have been to post your own answer and let the voters decide which was best? Or alternatively add a comment and let the OP of the answer decide if you were right

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure if you deserve the *would-be* batch (*having proposed it yourself*).

Comment: How to define (and check in program without much effort) that the edit was reputation-saving? It's like a hurricane-butterfly badge for someone who have posted comment or voted exactly 13 hours 13 minutes 13 seconds before the question was deleted etc.